# Auto sequential numbering based on cell criteria with two numbering sequences and ability to ignore duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In the example below the numbering in column A skips rows that have the word "TOTAL" in column C but picks right up again in the next rows. The rows with the word "TOTAL" in column C have their  own numbering.

As an example – if some rows contain "TOTAL", column A would be:

```
   Col A   Col C 
    1        S
    2        S
    1      TOTAL
    3        S
    2      TOTAL
    3      TOTAL
    4        S
    5        S
    4      TOTAL
```

To achieve the above this formula

```
=IF(C1="TOTAL", COUNTIF(C$1:C1,"TOTAL"), ROW(A1)-COUNTIF(C$1:C1,"TOTAL"))
```

was used. It works, yet it doesn't automatically propagate in column A (needs to be copied down the column – which is bearable).

ISSIUE: Sometimes "TOTAL" or "S" in Col C refers to the same item (Col D), so there is a need to keep the same number. How to ignore some rows but still continue the numbering? The desired outcome:

```
   Col A   Col C   Col D
    1        S      5A6
    2        S      XD3
    1      TOTAL    4GH
    3        S      D44
    2      TOTAL *  V2S
    2      TOTAL *  V2S
    4        S      GF3
    4        S      GF3 
    3      TOTAL    345
```

Comment: 1. Can there be more than two TOTAL entries for the same value in col D?   2. Will all multiples (TOTAL + matching col D value), always be consecutive (no other intervening records)?  3. Are the asterisks there just to highlight the feature or do you want "TOTAL *" on records that are multiples?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. They will always be consecutive. 3. Asterisks are there just to highlight the feature and will not appear in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applaud your effort to generate two sequences from one formula,
but I submit that this is hard to maintain. 
I recommend that you establish the two sequences in two separate columns (“helper” columns),
and then fuse them in column `A`.  For example,

- `A1` — `=IF(C1="TOTAL", X1, Y1)`, and drag down
- `X1` — `=IF(C1="TOTAL", 1, 0)`
- `X2` — `=IF(C2="TOTAL", IF(AND(C1="TOTAL", D1=D2), X1, X1+1), X1)`, and drag down
- `Y1` — `1`
- `Y2` — `=IF(C2="TOTAL", Y1, Y1+1)`, and drag down

Columns `X` and `Y` will be "out of sight", and you can hide them if you want.

Comment: This works beautifully but none of those formulas propagate down the column automatically when a new row is added, I tried to add "ARRRAYFOURMULA" but without success :(

Comment: Marcin - as with the other problem, I believe the only way to populate the formula "on demand" is to either pre-populate it and use a test like ISBLANK to hide it until there is an entry, or use VBA to put the formula or result in place when triggered by an entry.  There are limits to the magic.

Comment: G-Man- thank you! Can the formula from X2 be modified to also take into account the repeating "S" (as show in the edited question above)? fixer1234- I've posted a question about VBA- not only did it not get a response, but I'm also getting downvoted on it, I must have done sth wrong...

Comment: Can the formula from X2 be modified to also take into account the repeating "S" (as shown in the edited question above)? No. Do you even understand the answer I gave you? To change the column A result for rows that _don't_ have the text `TOTAL` in column C, you will need to change the formula in ***Y2***, to something like `=IF(C2="TOTAL", Y1, IF(AND(C1="S", C2="S", D1=D2), Y1, Y1+1))`.

Comment: G-Man- that worked. I've only simplified the problem in the above question- I'm applying those formulas in a much brader context... sometimes I'm just getting lost... sorry about that!

Comment: @Marcin: If this answer solved your problem, please indicate that by [marking it as accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.